# How do I apply vanilla JS to each character typed by the Typewriter.js API?

Tags: javascript

I am using `Typewriter.js` to type text to the screen. It works well, but I want to build more functionality and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I've tried to use the `callFunction` method from the API and it is pausing the execution of the `Typewriter`.

Ideally, I'd like the code to random the color of each character as it types. I can't seem to figure out how to get that to work and am wondering if it will at all at this point.

```
var app = document.getElementById('typewriter');
var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  loop: false,
  delay: 75,
});

typewriter
  .start()  
  .pauseFor(2500)
  .typeString('Hi.')
  .pauseFor(1500)
  .deleteAll(80)
  .typeString('Here are some words to type.')
  .pauseFor(3500)
  .deleteAll(40);

//-----------

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('typewriter'),
        txt = x.textContent,
        newText = "";
    for(var i=0, l=txt.length; i<l; i++) {
        newText += txt.charAt(i).fontcolor(getColor());
    }
    x.innerHTML = newText;
    console.log('test');  
}

function getColor() {
    var colorString="";
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*17);
        hexNum = num.toString(16);
        colorString += hexNum;
    }    
    return colorString;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I found Typewriter.js **before** I found typed.js. Typed is a much more robust library, it seems. After `V. Sambor` helped, I got this working with Typewriter.js. Then, about an hour and a half later, I stumbled across Typed.js trying to find a solution to a problem I was having with Typewriter.js.

After studying the Typed.js library, I wanted to come back here and suggest its use over the Typewriter.js library. The Typed library offers much more control and many more options.

https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js
vs
https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs

I wanted to test to see how easy it would be to add the solution that `V. Sambor` gave me to the a Typed.js solution and here is the result of that.

```
const getRandomColor = () => `rgb(${[1, 2, 3].map(x => Math.random() * 256 | 0)})`
const getColoredChar = (char, color) => `<span style="color: ${color || getRandomColor()}">${char}</span>`

var options = {
  strings: [getColoredChar('hello', '#fd5b78')],
  typeSpeed: 40
}

var typed = new Typed("#app", options);
```

As you can see, this is immediately easier to use.

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/willWashington/pen/zYOpdGv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documentation on `Typewriter` library, I've noticed they provide a way to pass a css class for the text wrapper on which you can set the color or you can even add html elements to the text, but the problem is you are limited to one node per `typeString` call.

Therefore I have created a function which adds a random or wished color to a character and passed it to the `typeString` multiple times. This looked great, but there was still another issue. The animation does not work fluently anymore, since it is a character per function now...
But fortunately I have found they provide a parameter called `delay` which allows to control animation speed delay, and this seems pretty good.

Here is my final idea:

```js
const typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  loop: true,
  delay: 33
});

typewriter.coloredTypeString = (string, color) => {
  const getRandomColor = () => `rgb(${[1, 2, 3].map(x => Math.random() * 256 | 0)})`
  const getColoredChar = (char, color) => `<span style="color: ${color || getRandomColor()}">${char}</span>`

  for (const char of string) {
    typewriter.typeString(getColoredChar(char, color))
  }

  return typewriter
}

typewriter
  .coloredTypeString('Hello ')
  .pauseFor(1500)
  .coloredTypeString('Beautiful ', 'red')
  .pauseFor(1500)
  .coloredTypeString('World!')
  .pauseFor(1500)
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

P.S. I didn't try any performance tests, maybe this would be necessary before putting it in somewhere in use...

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work, but it does give me an idea. I'm wondering if I can loop through an array of strings and return them to the .typeString method. I'll give this a shot when I get more time today and report back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can do that, so you don't have to write letters separately, the porblem with that seems to be that the animation speed is not good (it's just too slow, because it considers letter by letter, not 1 word...) I will look to see for a workaround...

Comment: Teach me, please. :)

Comment: It works wonderfully! I thought about doing something similar to this myself last night, but I'm not knowledgeable enough yet to pull it off. I'm going to study this and manipulate it to be what I need.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @w2- Welcome and have a great day!